# Fermion anti-commutation relations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fermions, anticommutator

The fermion anti-commutation relations are given as $$\{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),\psi_{\beta}^{\dagger}{(\bf x'},t)\} = \delta_{\alpha,\beta} \, \delta({\bf x} - {\bf x'}).$$ I am interested in determining $\{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),{\bar \psi}{(\bf x'},t) \psi({\bf x'},t)\}$. Does $\{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),{\bar \psi}_{\beta} ({\bf x'},t)\}$ simplify to anything? In general you have $\{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),(\psi^{\dagger}({\bf x'},t) \, \gamma^0)_{\beta}\}$ which is equal to $$\{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),\psi^{\dagger}_{\rho}({\bf x'},t) \gamma^0_{\rho\beta}\},$$ with the sum over $\rho$ assumed. In the energy representation, for example, it is straightforward to check that the $\gamma^0_{\rho\beta}$ can be taken outside the anti-commutator, but how do you show this in general (if instead of $\gamma^0$ you had, say, $\gamma^1$ then this is not so obvious since the $\gamma_1$ involves the Pauli matrix $\sigma_1$ and the spinor $\psi$ also involves $\sigma$ so it doesn't look easy to see that it would be true in this case)?

Comment: What kind of indices are the $\alpha,\beta$? Are there any of them missing in $\{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),{\bar \psi}{(\bf x'},t) \psi({\bf x'},t)\}$?

Comment: the $\alpha, \beta$ are components of the spinor $\psi$.

Comment: $\gamma^\mu$ is a number. The (anti-)commutator is taken between operators. A $c$-number may always be taken out of any (anti-)commutator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly state:
\begin{align}
  \{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),{\bar \psi}_{\beta} ({\bf x'},t)\} &=
  \{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),(\psi^{\dagger}({\bf x'},t) \,
  \gamma^0)_{\beta}\} =
  \{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),\psi^{\dagger}_{\rho}({\bf x'},t)
  \gamma^0_{\rho\beta}\} \\
  &= \psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t)\psi^{\dagger}_{\rho}({\bf x'},t)
  \gamma^0_{\rho\beta} + \psi^{\dagger}_{\rho}({\bf x'},t)
  \gamma^0_{\rho\beta} \psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t) \\
  &= \gamma^0_{\rho\beta}\left(\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t)
  \psi^{\dagger}_{\rho}({\bf x'},t)
   + \psi^{\dagger}_{\rho}({\bf x'},t)
  \psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t)\right) \\
  &= \gamma^0_{\rho\beta}
  \{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),\psi^{\dagger}_{\rho}({\bf x'},t)
  \} \\
  &= \gamma^0_{\alpha\beta}\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')
\end{align}

After explicitly writing indices on everything, we are just dealing with products of (Grassman) numbers. $\gamma^0_{\alpha\beta}$  commutes with any other element, so it can be taken out.

The commutation relations between $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}\psi$ should be expressed as commutators, because $\psi$ is a fermion and $\bar{\psi}\psi$ is a boson. Using the equation above and $\{\psi_\alpha(\mathbf{x},t),\psi_\beta(\mathbf{x}',t)\}=0$ we get
\begin{align}
  [\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),{\bar \psi}{(\bf x'},t) \psi({\bf x'},t)]
  =& [\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),{\bar \psi}_\beta{(\bf x'},t)
  \psi_\beta({\bf x'},t)] \\
  =& \psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t){\bar \psi}_\beta{(\bf x'},t)
  \psi_\beta({\bf x'},t) -
  {\bar \psi}_\beta{(\bf x'},t)\psi_\beta({\bf x'},t)
  \psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t) \\
  =& -\{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),{\bar \psi}_\beta{(\bf x'},t)\}
  \psi_\beta({\bf x'},t) -
  {\bar \psi}_\beta{(\bf x'},t)\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t)
  \psi_\beta({\bf x'},t) \\ &-
  {\bar \psi}_\beta{(\bf x'},t)\psi_\beta({\bf x'},t)
  \psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t) \\
  =& -\delta_{\alpha\beta}
  \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')\psi_\beta({\bf x'},t)-
  {\bar \psi}_\beta{(\bf x'},t)
  \{\psi_{\alpha}({\bf x},t),\psi_{\beta} ({\bf x'},t)\} \\
  =& -\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')\psi_\alpha({\bf x'},t)
\end{align}